# Do Azure workflows need additional authentication considerations?

Tags: csv, azure, parallel-processing, workflow, powershell-ise

I'm unable to deploy availability sets in parallel from a simple table from Powershell ISE onto my MSDN subscription.

Table

`Type  RG  Name               Loc 
AvSet NLG NLGUTCDCPWFEAVL01  eastus2 
AvSet NLG NLGUTCDCPAPPAVL01  eastus2 
AvSet NLG NLGUTCDCPCCDBAVL01 eastus2`

This works when executed without a workflow.

`$c=Import-Csv C:\Users\ayanm\Downloads\NLG.csv|? type -eq 'AVSet'
   foreach ($b in $c)
    {New-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName $b.RG -Name $b.name -Location $b.loc}`

But when I try to put it in a workflow, it doesn't

`Workflow Deploy-AVSet
   {$c=Import-Csv C:\Users\ayanm\Downloads\NLG.csv|? type -eq 'AVSet'
    foreach -Parallel ($b in $c)
      {New-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName $b.RG -Name $b.name -Location $b.loc}
        }`

Error:
`Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At Deploy-AVSet:4 char:4
+ CategoryInfo     : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand`

Checked Powershell version; 5.1. Updated all modules. Rebooted computer. Is this an unsupported workflow activity?
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Login-AzureRmAccount' cmdlet doesn't MSDN crediantial object. So I added an O365 account as an owner of the subscription and am able to deploy in parallel.

`Workflow Deploy-AVSet
  {$c=Import-Csv C:\Users\ayanm\Downloads\NLG.csv|? type -eq 'AVSet'
   $cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "name@domain.onmicrosoft.com",$(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -asplaintext -force)
    foreach ($b in $c)
        {AzureRM.Resources\Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
         New-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName $b.RG -Name $b.name -Location $b.loc -PlatformFaultDomainCount $b.faultdomain -PlatformUpdateDomainCount $b.UpdateDomain
         }
  }`